# ASP.NET Application integration with Vaadin

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, vaadin

I'd like to first of all say that I have very little programming experience so please do excuse my ignorance.

I am currently making a medical web-based application using ASP.NET. We have finished a few different sections, including the admin section. But when I came by Vaadin again a few weeks ago, I completely fell in love with it and decided that I really would like to replace the old Admin with something that looks like the Runo theme.

However, as far as I understand it, ASP.NET and JavaScript do not mix, and I was told that it would be possible to integrate Vaadin into my application.

I am wondering if you know anyway that can help me implement this? Any help what so ever would be great.

Comment: Vaadin is java-based, java != javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am currently making a medical web-based application using ASP.NET
>
> I was told that it would be possible to integrate Vaadin into my application.

No it's not possible. Vaadin is based on Java Servlets API and GWT while ASP.NET has whole different concept.

In fact, supporting C# and .NET by Vaadin team [was year ago an April Fools Day joke](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/vaadin-switching-to-c-1)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply... Acutaully i'm am new to Vaadin i don't know anything about vaadin. The only thing i know is - it is used for UI developement.
so i was thinking to develope UI through vaadin and rest things in C# .net. 
Is it possible ???

Comment: No, It's not. If you want Vaadin Components in your User Interface you need to develop your application in Java.

Comment: And you would have to deploy in a [Java Servlet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) container such as [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org) or Eclipse Jetty  rather than an ASP server.

Comment: Thanx Everyone. !! 
It was really helpful..
.
I have one more query like can i integrate vaadin with .net Application using JNI ??

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to separate the two applications via IFrame and have them communicate via HTML5 postMessage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage). You still have to do some plumbing in the backend (e.g. a shared database), but it could be a way to move forward without actually throwing away what you have in ASP.NET

//EDIT: I did write a blog post some time ago - unfortunately only in German, maybe still helpful: http://blog-de.akquinet.de/2015/02/04/renewal-legacy-ui-vaadin-html5-postmessage/